# Destroying thread and exiting loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm creating a thread like this:

main.cpp

```
    QThread acceptorThread;
    acceptorObject acceptorobject;
    acceptorobject.setupConnections(acceptorThread, simulation);
    acceptorobject.moveToThread(&acceptorThread);
```

acceptorObject.cpp

```
void acceptorObject::setupConnections(QThread& thread, Simulation * simulation)
{
    QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(acceptNewClients()));
}
```

acceptNewClients() method works in infinite loop. At this point if I close my program I would get an error:

```
QThread destroyed while thread is still running
```

I looked through similar problems at stack and one guy said that I need to break the loop before finishing the thread in order to get rid of this bug. He also suggested to use a flag in infinite loop and emit a signal in destructor that will change the flag and eventually break the loop. It KINDA worked when I did something like this:

```
QObject::connect(&thread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(acceptNewClients()));
QObject::connect(this, SIGNAL(finishThread(bool)), this, SLOT(acceptNewClients(bool)));
```

And then emited finishThread(true) signal from destructor so I directly changed the flag. Of course I changed slot signature as well so it won't run in new thread anymore.

destructor code:

```
emit finishThread(true);

this->thread()->quit();
if(!this->thread()->wait(3000))
{
    this->thread()->terminate();
    this->thread()->wait();
}
```

### How can I make this work?

What I've tried so far:

- Adding a new slot that will change the flag. Result: when I close program the window dissapears but the proccess is still running. I think that destructor destroys the object before its emited signal is proccessed .
- Making bool argument in acceptNewClients() slot a default one. Result: it overloads the funtion so one is run in different thread and the second one tries to change the flag which obviously doesn't work because they are completely different functions.

Comment: Maybe you should try add connection `connect(this, SIGNAL(destroyed()), &thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));` Then you don't need your destructor's code. Once object deleted, thread will deleted too.

Comment: I tried this before. It gets back to the "QThread destroyed while thread is still running" problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(finishThread()), &thread, SLOT(quit()));
connect(this, SIGNAL(finishThread()), this, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

It was pointless to change slot function signature in this case.
In deconstructor I simply emit finishThread() signal, nothing more.

Comment: Further reading: [How To Really, Truly Use QThreads](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) by Maya Posch

Answer (score 0):

One way is instead of doing a `while(true)` in `acceptNewClients` you instead do

```
void acceptorObject::acceptNewClients(){
    // do accept new client

    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "acceptNewClients",  Qt::QueuedConnection);
}
```

In essence making the loop external.

The other option is to make everything use signals, `QTcpServer` (which I think you are using) has a `newConnection` signal you can connect to. Instead of using `waitForNewConnection`.

Comment: Well this method is one of few that need to work in this fashion.
I use boost libraries for server, but after seeing this I think I need to switch to QTcpServer in order to make it easier.

I'll mess around with your solution.

Comment: @JustMike you need to have a blocking wait? There is often a way to limit the wait time (a timeout) you can use that and a timer to keep polling.

Comment: I meant I have three threads running in the background with infinite loops inside: one for accepting clients, one for collecting data from clients and one for proccessing data received from clients. (They're already secured  to avoid busy waiting.) My main problem is that with this approach of creating threads (which I heard is recommended) I won't be able to exit these loops, because thread signal started takes no arguments and therefore is incompatibile with slots with flag arguments.

Comment: I feel like it would be the best idea to try to avoid using infinite loops.